# How to code Android app to download songs from webserver and play from sdcard

Tags: android, download, android-sdcard

I am planning to build a media player app in Android. On clicking a link in this app, the app would first download the media (mp3 file) to the phone's sd card. Once the download is done, the player would start playing the file.

I was wondering if this is possible -
1. The download happens in the background, without the user knowing anything about the download process
2. The app still remains in focus while the download happens, so that user is kept totally unaware of the process, and he can continue using the other parts of this app

The file would come from a website that I am hosting. It is a php site.
For example, the site would have mp3 in the server, and links to songs would be in this format - www.abc.com/
The app would have say 10 icons initially, and each icon would be a link to one of the songs in this website. SO icon1 would actually point to www.abc.com/song1.mp3, and so on.

So the whole question revolves around the process of downloading and then playing from the sdcard once song1.mp3 has been downloaded.

Any pointers on how to do this is really appreciated.
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. The download happens in the background, without the user knowing anything about the download process

Start an AsyncTask or Thread to do the download using standard Java IO APIs to read and save the file to the SD Card.

Once you have finished downloading the file, simply use either SoundPool or MediaPlayer to play it.